# Proper usage of property in pyhon

Tags: python, properties

I've met an interesting situation with usage of the properties in python. The property is defined as a method with decorator `@property`:

```
@hybrid_property
def purchase_date(self) -> datetime:
    return self.suborder.buyout_date
```

I have a hybrid property but I believe it doesn't change the case.

I try then to use a property in another method of same class:

```
temp = self.purchase_date
print(temp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

As I expect type of property value to be `datetime` I don't expect any problems here. However I'm getting an error:
`AttributeError: 'hybrid_property' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

So, I try to dig deeper into what the property is. I know it's a method. So probably when I do assignment I don't assign the property value but just a function. Ok, call the method:

```
temp = self.purchase_date()
```

... and get an error `'hybrid_property' is not callable`

So I dig even deeper and checked properties of the self.purchase_date. I see there is `fget` method so I try to call it:

```
temp = self.purchase_date.fget(self)
```

Now I've got expected value. My question is - is it normal way to use properties in Python?

Comment: what is `hybrid_property`???

Comment: And no, this is definitely not how you are supposed to use properties. If it *were* a `property`, your original code should just work. You really must provide a [mcve]

Comment: So, this seems to be some custom descriptor from sqlalchemy, correct? It definitely behaves differently than `property`.  Again, though, you need to provide a [mcve]. Just a hunch, are you using Python 2?

Comment: Ok, you're right. Using ```@property``` gives expected behavior. It's ```@hybrid_property```, who causes issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The pure Python `@property` behaves exactly as a reqular attribute including handling `setattr(instance, property)` in terms that setter is called.

The problem occurs on `@hybrid_property`, which is sqlalchemy decorator and implemented in a different way.